# HTML / MYSQL Character Display

Tags: html, mysql, character

I display a cell value from a MYSQL-Table in a PHP/HTML-Website.

I'm from Switzerland, we use special-letters like " Ö ö Ä ä Ü ü "

Usually, these letters work when they are in direct html like `<p> Zurück </p>`.

But when they come from mysqli-query it looks like `<p>^Zur-(Salino-shape with ? inside)-ck <p>`

Why is this?

Here are my settings:

table-row :

`type: text ;   collation : utf32-german-ci ;    Null: No;    Auto-Increment: No;`

html-meta:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-32" />`

i also tried to Switch row and html to different charsets but it doesnt change.

Comment: Check the charset in php, you need to make sure php, mysql and html have matching charsets

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: where i find charset in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set charset as `utf8`

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: why not 32.. utf32 has more characters ..hasnt it?

Comment: Solution works perfect. But i really. Thank you very much :)


would like use 32..